# Trying to iterate over pyspark data frame without using spark_df.collect()

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

HI I am trying to iterate over pyspark data frame without using `spark_df.collect()` and I am trying foreach and map method is there any other way to iterate?

`df.foreach(lambda x: print(x))` and

````
def func1(x):
    firstname=x.firstname
    lastName=x.lastName
    name=firstName+","+lastName
    gender=x.gender.lower()
    salary=x.salary*2
    return (name,gender,salary)```

```rdd2=df.rdd.map(lambda x: func1(x))```

is there any other way to iterate over data frame
````

Comment: see [`toLocalIterator()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toLocalIterator.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-tolocaliterator)

Comment: py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public static java.lang.Object[] org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.toLocalIteratorAndServe(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD,boolean) is not whitelisted on class class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD got this error

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Spark is not made to do such kind of operations, like printing each records but more on distributed processing. Tune your process to work in a distributed fashion, like in terms of joins - that will unleash the power of spark.

If you want to process each record, UDFs ([User defined functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html)) are a good way to do that. UDFs will be applied to each record once.

Answer (score 0):

we can use this method to iterate over rows

````
pandasDF = df.toPandas()
for index, row in pandasDF.iterrows():
    print(row['itm_mtl_no'], row['itm_src_sys_cd']) ```
````

Comment: this uses `toPandas()`, which is kind of same as `collect` though.